# JavaScript While Loop that generates Divs not working

Tags: javascript, html, while-loop

This HTML file has a script tag that is suppose to create colorful div squares within the divs [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Puo.png) but the JavaScript is not showing up on onload.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>An Example Project</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
    <style>
        div {position:absolute}
    </style>

</head>
<body id="theBody" onload="show_pattern()">
<script>
        function show_pattern() {
            var top_position = 25, left_position = 25; // set up variables
            var width = 500, height = 500;
            var color_list = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
            var the_body = document.getElementById("theBody"); //add div node to body

            while (width > 50) {
                var this_div = document.createElement("div");
                var random_color = Math.random() * 7; //0-6.999
                random_color = Math.floor(random_color); // 0-6 (7 total from list)
                this_div.style.top = top_position + "px";
                this_div.style.left = left_position + "px";
                this_div.width = width + "px";
                this_div.style.height = height + "px";
                this_div.style.background = color_list[random_color];
                the_body.appendChild(this_div);
                top_position += 10;
                left_position += 10;
                width -= 20;
                height -= 20;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the width correctly. It should be

```
this_div.style.width = width + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

The code probably has a logic error. Beyond that it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/usLv6rzh/

```
<body id="theBody" onload="show_pattern()">
<script>
        function show_pattern() {
            var top_position = 25, left_position = 25; // set up variables
            var width = 500, height = 500;
            var color_list = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
            var the_body = document.getElementById("theBody"); //add div node to body

            while (width > 50) {
                var this_div = document.createElement("div");
                var random_color = Math.random() * 7; //0-6.999
                random_color = Math.floor(random_color); // 0-6 (7 total from list)
                this_div.style.top = top_position + "px";
                this_div.style.left = left_position + "px";
                this_div.width = width + "px";
                this_div.style.height = height + "px";
                this_div.style.background = color_list[random_color];
                the_body.appendChild(this_div);
                top_position += 10;
                left_position += 10;
                width -= 20;
                height -= 20;
    }
}
</script>
```